# Django rest framework add more data when serialize many object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I would like to add an additional field for user's details. But it has to use another value outside of database fields.
For more clearly like this

**model:**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    role_id = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializer:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    display_summary = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    login_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id","last_name","first_name", "display_summary", "login_user_id")

    def get_display_summary(self, obj):
        login_id    = self.validated_data.get('login_user_id', None)
        login_user  = User.objects.filter(pk=login_id).first()
        if obj.role_id==2 and login_user.role_id==1:
            return 1

        return 0
```

So in my views, when getting just one user, it's all ok:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@login_required
def get_user(request, login_user, user_id):
    serializer = UserSerializer(User.objects.get(pk=user_id), data={'login_user_id': login_user.id})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        result = serializer.data
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

#result:
#{
#    "id": 2,
#    "last_name": "V",
#    "first_name": "Lich",
#    "role_id": 2,
#    "display_summary": 1
#}
```

But when I need to return a list, how can I add additional data (login_user_id)?
This is not working:

```
users = User.objects.filter(last_name__icontains='v')
result_serializer = UserSerializer(users, data={'login_user_id': login_user.id}, many=True)
return result_serializer.data
```

The error occur say that it's looking for a list, not a dict for inputted param.

Comment: users is a list and data is a dictionary, why it should work correct?

Comment: Thanks for having attention to my answer. Maybe my English is too ugly, I meant to ask how can I get a list of users, with each one running through UserSerializer for adding custom field that use outside data from database query object?

Comment: As you want to work with list, you should pass list of dict to `data` parameters. Example (just a mock data): `result_serializer = UserSerializer(users, data=[{'login_user_id': login_id_1}, {'login_user_id': login_id_2}], many=True)`

Comment: @LucVH do you wish to add the same `login_user_id` value to each user in the list? Or should each user get a different `login_user_id` value?

Comment: @WillKeeling: I wish to add the same login_user_id value to each user in the list

Comment: @LucVH Since you're passing the `login_user` to determine the `display_summary` value, perhaps a better approach may be to use an `__init__` argument for the `login_user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Hai Lang 's idea, I made a new namedtuple to add more info. Something like this:

**Serializer:**
No use ModelSerializer, use normal Serializer with field I would like to show on this view

```
class UserSummarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    last_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    first_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    display_summary = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def validate(self, data):
        #some validation if needed
        return data
    def get_user_id(self, obj):
        return obj.user.user_id
    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name
    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name
    def get_display_summary(self, obj):
        login_user  = obj.login_user
        if obj.role_id==2 and login_user.role_id==1:
            return 1

        return 0
```

then in my views:

```
userSummary = namedtuple('userSummary ', ('user', 'login_user'))
users = User.objects.filter(last_name__icontains='v')
objs  = [userSummary(u, login_user) for u in users]
result_serializer = UserSerializer(objs, many=True)
return result_serializer.data
```